# Is the checkin object's type=mayorship notification appears fickle?

Tags: api, foursquare

I have some questions about 4sq's API.

Chceckin object obtained by checkins/add endpoint's response sometimes has mayorship field and  at other times not.

And mayorship's checkins count field seems not reliable (often appears count 0, but actual count is 2).

Is it so?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The notification only contains mayor information if the user is somewhat close to being able to claim the mayorship.

As for incorrect checkin counts, you'll need to provide an example response for us to be able to debug.

Comment: For example,
checkins/add to venue_id = 4c8b9afc52a98cfa085e37e9 returns,
`stdClass::__set_state(array( 'type' => 'mayorship', 'item' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'type' => 'nochange', **'checkins' => 0**, ...
`
and venues/4c8b9afc52a98cfa085e37e9 rerturns,
`'mayor' => stdClass::__set_state(array( **'count' => 2**, ...
`

Comment: You need to paste actual response JSON